# What is the best way to switch between UIViewControllers without using a navigation controller in storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Please refer to the image below -

I'm not using NavigationViewController. Is there a way to switch between views when using storyboard and segues? I know the other way around would be to use a root view controller and switch views that way. Just wanted to know if there is a alternative way of doing this.

Thanks!

[image: storyboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

1. Use a navigation controller, but just hide it (both in the Interface Builder design of the storyboard, as well as programmatically at runtime via `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` in your `viewDidLoad`). Thus `pushViewController` (or a simple push segue) and `popViewController` work, without the navigation bar user interface.
2. Use modal segues (i.e. behind the scenes it will do `presentViewControllerAnimated`) and `dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

Comment: So I just need to set an identifier for the segue and set the type as 'modal' and then use [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:sender];

Is that correct?

Comment: What if I want to go back to the Initial View? Do I need a segue from the second view back to the first view? (In this case - how do I go back to LoginViewController from LoginSuccessViewController or ResgiterSuccessViewController?)

Comment: @wackytacky99 Just call `dismissViewControllerAnimated` from the respective confirmation view controller.

Answer (score 1):

It does not require a navigationController to use a segue. Just use the `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:sender];`
 line anywhere you have a Segue set up and identified in your Storyboard.

Comment: You still need to decide whether that segue is a `push` or `modal` segue, right? And you can't push unless you have the navigation controller. And even if you do a `custom` segue, your custom code needs to decide to `pushViewController` or `presentViewControllerAnimated`.